# Unable to apply class to specific url

Tags: css, conditional-statements, blogger

I'm trying to get conditional CSS to work in Blogger / Blogspot - no matter wat i try it doesn't seem to work,
mycss is

```
.aboutme-container{
  display:flex;
  flex:1;
  color:#000;
}
```

So what i want to do is, turn off the display for the particular div if the url is not  the specific url , but it turns it off on all urls , the code is

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url != "https://memerqueen.blogspot.com/p/aboutme.html"'>
<style>
  .aboutme-container  {
    display:none;
  }
</style>
</b:if>
```

Comment: you have an error at http:// https:// You must choose only one. Other than that, I see no reason why don't work.

Comment: i corrected that still problem persists

Comment: `Style` tags is a global tags. if at least one of the condition meets then the style tags will apply to all the site. so use style property instead